# Usage of so and also

Tags: difference

What is the difference between also and so? Do they all mean 'so'?

1. Jana war nicht im Park, ***also*** bin ich nach Hause zurückgekehrt.
2. Jana war nicht im Park, ***so*** bin ich nach Hause zurückgekehrt.

Are so and also interchangeable?

Comment: Relevant:http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1867/so-in-german-meanings-and-usages/1878 , as well as this here: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8206/word-order-with-so-and-also

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The German *so* and *also* as well as the English counterparts come from a word that meant

> In that way

The German *so* has kept this meaning pretty much while the English *so* has evolved. One of its functions is a conjunction that expresses consequence. The German *so* does not have that function at all. A proper translation would be German *also*

> I was tired so I went to bed.
>
> Ich war müde, also bin ich ins Bett gegangen.

On a side note: German *also* is an adverb rather than a conjunction so you can move it to different places in your sentence.
German *so* and *also* are never interchangeable. If you want a more detailed comparison between German and English, you can check out the post I've written about this o[n my blog](http://yourdailygerman.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/meaning-german-so/).

Comment: You say "so and also are never interchangeable", but IMHO the example given above is exactly such a case. E.g. in literature you can find expressions like "..., so zog er denn unverrichteter Dinge von Dannen.", which in meaning is identical to "..., also ging er wieder, ohne seine Arbeit zu tun."

Comment: @dog das wird dann aber eher am Satzanfang gemacht und ich halte es im "Binnendeutsch" für falsch, da "so" in erster Linie "in dieser Weise" heißt. "Ich war müde, so bin ich ins Bett gegangen" klingt falsch für mich und ich würde es als "Ich war müde, und müde bin ich ins Bett gegangen."

Answer (score 5):

They're not interchangeable. Overuse of *so* where *also* would be required is one of the most common giveaways of English native speakers in German. *Also* must be used whenever the English *so* could be replaced by *therefore*. The German *so* almost always means "in that way". "So geht das!" - "that's how it's done!"