# Usage of "so eine"

Tags: grammar

I know that "So eine Überraschung!" means "What a surprise!"

In this case, is "eine" nominative or accusative? What does "so" mean in this case and are there other examples of "so eine ... " ?

Comment: related http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1867/so-in-german-meanings-and-usages

Answer (score 3):

> So eine Überraschung! [... hätte ich jetzt nicht erwartet!]

The expression generally serves the purpose of saying out a surprising / disgusting / outraging thing aloud, which everyone surely knows an instinctive comment to. In the example above, something (the handing over of a present?) is moved into the center of attention, but there's no need to tell everyone that the person is excited, because that would only repeat the instinctive reaction of everyone.

`So eine Überraschung` is the subject of surprise here, it is the thing that the "inner comment/reaction" refers to. The casus of the subject depends on the "extension". In this example, `So` precises the sentence to mean that the subject would be "this {specific kind of} surprise (of recieving a present)".

A longer version of this type of expression is:

> So was aber auch! [... sollte eigentlich verboten sein!]

Here, `aber auch` further emphasizes the disgust / outrage of the person saying it. Again, the sentence could be implicitly lengthened as above.

Comment: Just so there is no misunderstanding: It should be noted that the first sentence *cannot* be extended as shown above to recognize the case, as "eine Überraschung" would actually be accusative in "So eine Überraschung hätte ich jetzt nicht erwartet."

Comment: Oh yeah, that's true ... so the subject's casus depends on the "extension". Thanks Mapper

Comment: Just to clarify, "*So eine Überraschung*" is not necessarily negative. I would actually only use it as a politely positive expression: e.g. when your Stepmother comes for a visit without telling you "*So eine Überraschung! Das freut mich aber, dich zu sehen*".. In this case it is polite because it makes the other person comfortable and welcome. No matter if one considers it a positive or negative surprise.

Comment: Yeah, I actually intended to make it sound like a positive surprise too, as it doesn't normally mean something negative when Germans say "I really didn't expect that".

Answer (score 2):

As a native German speaker, I would perhaps have (mis)translated it as "Such a surprise!"

In German, "so ein(e)" is often used to indicate a distinct or special possibility among others.

To stay with the example, there were various possibilities for a surprise, but I haven't expected such a surprise, so I have to say: "What a surprise!"

Please excuse my English ;-)